# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) in voter partial

Tags: ruby, arguments

```
Showing /home/vagrant/code/bloccit/app/views/votes/_voter.html.erb where line #6 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #6):


    <div><%= link_to " ", 
        post_up_vote_path(post), 
        class: up_vote_link_classes(post), method: :post %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/_post.html.erb, app/views/topics/show.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/vagrant/code/bloccit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:20:in `voted'
app/models/user.rb:21:in`voted'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:26:in `up_vote_link_classes'
app/views/votes/_voter.html.erb:6:in`_app_views_votes__voter_html_erb___418536146_80757250'
app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb___621990029_79333610'
app/views/topics/show.html.erb:10:in`_app_views_topics_show_html_erb__712368041_99038610'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

in my voter partial

```
<% if policy(Vote.new).create? %>
<div class="vote-arrows pull-left">

    <div><%= link_to " ", 
        post_up_vote_path(post), 
        class: up_vote_link_classes(post), method: :post %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>
            <%= post.points %>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div><%= link_to " ", 
        post_down_vote_path(post), 
        class: down_vote_link_classes(post), method: :post %>
    </div>
</div>  
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy 
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy

def role?(base_role)
    role == base_role.to_s
end  

def favorited(post)
  favorites.where(post_id: post.id).first
end  

def voted(post)
  voted.where(post_id: post.id).first
end   

def self.top_rated
  self.select('users.*') # Select all attributes of the user
      .select('COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) AS comments_count') # Count comments made my the user
      .select('COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id) AS posts_count') # Count the posts made by the user
      .select('COUNT(DISTINCT comments.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT posts.id) AS rank') # Add the comment count to the post count and label the sum as "rank"
      .joins(:posts) # Ties the posts table to the users table, via the user_id
      .joins(:comments) # Ties the comments table to the users table, via the user_id
      .group('users.id') # Instructs the database to group the results so that each user will be returned in a distinct row
      .order('rank DESC') # Instructs the database to order the results in descending order, by the rank that we created in this query. (rank = comment count + post count)
end       
end
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message together with backtrace?

Comment: @Amanjpot - thanks. Stack trace contains some methods which are application specific - could you please show `app/models/user.rb`?

Comment: there you go! @BroiSatse , thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `voted` method, you recursively call `voted`, instead of `votes`. Voted expect a param, hence you got an error. Change it to:

```
def voted(post)
  votes.where(post_id: post.id).first
end
```